# Get all ID in class Form to change "setCustomValidity" in text input form

Tags: javascript

here's the code

```
function getId(){
$.each($('.myForm'), function() {
var get = this.id ; \\ allert this & the masssage show with this id
var val = this.value ;
    if (val == ''){
        this.focus(); 
this.setCustomValidity('My custom validation message'); \\same message in each text
        return false;
    }else { return true; }});}
```

the problems is :
 a focus does not want to move (always be in textinput where already has a value)
what should I do to fix it?

Comment: What does "console.log(this, this.val)" says?

Comment: that says the value in each inputtext in a form...if a text have an value